# Can not access ubuntu computer on my windows xp pc

Tags: networking

I can see my ubuntu machine in the work group of my windows xp pc but when i click it says that it is not accessible/no permission/the parameter is incorrect etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few steps to follow..

First you have to install Samba on your Ubuntu machine

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
```

Then you have to modify `smb.conf`

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and find the line

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

based on your workgroup inside WinXP, modify this line accordingly. Maybe you don't have to modify this file at all. If you did modify it, restart Samba

```
sudo service samba restart
```

Now go back to WinXp and try again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your folder permissions so you can access it on the network
[image: permissions]